# everyone I know vs everyone whom I know

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, ellipsis

I've noticed that a lot of native English speakers leave out pronouns that help modify subjects. Is there any situation in which this:

> Everyone whom I know is related to me.

Is preferred to this:

> Everyone I know is related to me.

Or this:

> Everyone whom I've talked with is on the same page as me.

Is preferred to this:

> Everyone I've talked with is on the same page as me.

Comment: Everyone I know would prefer to leave out the ‘whom'

Answer (score 1):

While you are correct in thinking "***whom***" should be used since the object is animated, many natives will say

> Everyone **that** I know...
>   Everyone **that** I talked to...
>   Everyone **that** I spoke with...

These things you can only pick up through usage.